# No operator "<<" matches these operands - C++

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and starting my main university project. All is going well so far, however I have came across this problem and after hours of searching the web i'm still clueless.

The problem occurs in `Portfolio::displayAccounts()`when I am trying to loop through a vector to display each element inside the vector.

It will not allow me to use the typical `std::cout <<` which I have always used for things like arrays.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <vector>
#include "Account.h"


class Portfolio
{
private:
    std::vector<Account> accounts;

public:
    double calculateNetWorth();
    Portfolio();
    void addAccount(std::string name, double balance);
    void displayAccounts();
};
```

```
#include "Account.h"

double Account::getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

Account::Account(std::string name, double balance){
    this->name = name;
    this->balance = balance;
}
```

```
#include <string>
class Account
{
private:
    std::string name;
    double balance;
public: 
    double getBalance();
    Account(std::string name, double balance);
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

double Portfolio::calculateNetWorth() {
    double total = 0;
    for (auto& account : accounts) {
        total += account.getBalance();
    }
    return total;
}

Portfolio::Portfolio() {    

}

void Portfolio::addAccount(std::string name, double balance) {
    std::cout << "Account Name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Account Balance: ";
    std::cin >> balance;
    Account account = Account(name, balance);
    accounts.push_back(account);
}


void Portfolio::displayAccounts() {
    std::cout << "nThe vector elements after push back are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << accounts[i] << " ";
    }    
}
```

Comment: Where do you define a `operator <<` for `Account`?

Comment: You use the `<<` operator three times in the `displayAccounts` function. Which is the one with the error? Please help us help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library has no idea how an instance of your `Account` class should be outputted. In order to be able to write something like this:

```
std::cout << some_account;
```

you need to overload the `<<` operator, for example like this:

```
class Account
{
private:
  std::string name;
  double balance;
public:
  double getBalance();
  Account(std::string name, double balance);

  // add this so the overloaded << operator can access your private members
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Account& o);
};

// Implementation

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Account& a)
{
  os << "Name: " << a.name << "  Balance: " << a.balance << "\n";
  return os;
}
```

Will print something like this for an `Account` instance:

`Name: SomeName  Balance: 123.45678`

**Bonus:**

If you're using C++11 you can write this:

```
  for (auto & account : accounts)
    std::cout << account << " ";
```

instead of:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << accounts[i] << " ";
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to print `accounts[i]` which has the `Account` type. As your object does not have a `<<` overloaded operator, you won't be able to print anything. 
There are 2 solutions :

1. Overload the `<<` operator
2. Print rather the `name` or the `balance` attributes of your class